# javascript/jQuery is automatically updating data in div after data is retrieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building a Ruby on Rails application where I am performing an Ajax request to retrieve some data, perform calculations on it, and place it on the page.  The page is going to be performing these calculations every 30 seconds or so on new data from the database, so this means I need to keep the original data from the Ajax request intact.  When I'm retrieving the original data, I'm placing it in a div using jQuery like so:

```
$('#info').data('original', data);
```

and then taking that data object and running said calculations on it. After the calculations are complete, I place it in a separate data attribute in the same div like so:

```
$('#info').data('modified', data);
```

The data in the 'modified' attribute goes to the page, and when the time has come, it pulls the new data from the database, the original data from the div, gets passed to a method for calculating, and then is placed back in the 'modified' attribute for being displayed on the page:

```
function calculate(data) {
    // doing some stuff here
    $('#info').data('modified', data);
}

var data = $('#info').data('original');
calculate(data);
```

All of this is working just fine, however when the very first calculation is being ran, it seems that the 'original' attribute in the div is being overwritten with the data that has been calculated, even though I'm not explicitly telling it to do so.  Does anyone have any insight on why this could be happening?

Comment: The issue isn't clear, Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Because I don't understand the reasoning behind using .data and not .attr as others have had great debates on in other stack overflow questions, I'm not going to put this into a legit answer ... but i'll just say that using .attr instead of .data in this particular case may get you past your issue.